# HOw do i get all the data in a fieldname (Name) in database and store it in a variable array? in PHP and MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, database, arrays, loops

```
$name = mysql_num_rows($result);
$i = 0;
while($i < $name){  
    $nameAll = mysql_result($result, $i);           
    $i++;   
}
```

Comment: what should i do next? i want to store the value in $result[0] and so on.....sorry, im just a newbie in php. =) tnx in advance. God bless

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use code from the first example [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php).

```
$sql = "SELECT id as userid, fullname, userstatus 
        FROM   sometable
        WHERE  userstatus = 1";

    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    // While a row of data exists, put that row in $row as an associative array
    // Note: If you're expecting just one row, no need to use a loop
    // Note: If you put extract($row); inside the following loop, you'll
    //       then create $userid, $fullname, and $userstatus
    $values = array(); 
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

        $values[] = $row["fullname"];

    }
```

Comment: was just about to say you dont need the $i

Comment: tnx. but i have to get all the names based on the date between date-from and date-to. here's my query. select name from person where date-from between date-to. =) i'll your code first. tnx again. =)